# Multivariable limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} (x^2+y^2)^{x^2y^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I'm studying multivariable limits and I have a problem regarding this limit:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} (x^2+y^2)^{x^2y^2}.$$  I've found that it is equal to 1, by rewriting
the limit using $t = e^{\ln(t)}$. Despite this, the answer in the book is 0. What is the correct answer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using polar coordinates, we get

$$\begin{cases}x=r\cos t\\y=r\sin t\end{cases}\implies (x^2+y^2)^{x^2y^2}=r^{2r^4sin^2t\cos^2t}=r^{\frac12r^4\sin^22t}=e^{\frac12r^4\sin^22t\log r}\xrightarrow[r\to 0^+]{}e^0=1$$

so I'd go with you being correct and the book is wrong. What book is that, anyway?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $r^4$ in the exponent?

Comment: It's a college book from Romania :). Why it is correct to make that substitution? The limit means that we should consider all the pats to (0,0) not only those whose points lie on a straight line.

Comment: @timbuc consider Henrik's answer also

Comment: First, the above doesn't consider *only* straight paths, as the limit remains whatever the angle $\;t\;$ is. Second, it shows the limit **cannot** be zero as *at least* in the above way we got something different. La revedere acum.

Comment: Thank you, Julian. Editing

Comment: @godonichia, thank you. I hardly understand it, but also the easy path chosen by Henrik in his answer ($\;x=0\,,\,\,y\neq 0\;$) shows the limit cannot be zero, so something must be wrong there.

Comment: @Timbuc Exactly

Comment: @godonichia And now that answer has been edited to show the limit *cannot* be zero. Good.

Comment: Why should the angles of sin and cos be the same? If we must consider all the possible paths, why not x = r*cos(t) and y = r*sin(t2) ?

Comment: @SebiSebi, I didn't consider "all angles": I just showed the book cannot be right.

Comment: Ok. Now I understand. But this method cannot be used for finding limits, for instance.

Comment: Well, it can but with some conditions, which I don't think are so inflexible. I just can't remember now.

Answer (score 15):

If we examine what happens when we approach $(0,0)$ along the line $x=0$ (or $y=0$), we get:
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \left(x^2+y^2\right)^{x^2y^2}=
\lim_{y\to0} \left(0+y^2\right)^{0}=
1
$$

meaning that if the limit exists it must be $1$.

Comment: I'll vote up this answer as it is seriously shorter, simpler and more elegant that any other here, including mine. +1

Comment: This is incorrect: for example this limit
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac xy$$
doesn't exist however if you pass first to the limit $x\to0$ then you'll find the limit $0$.

Comment: That doesn't really change anything. I wrote "if the limit exists", I didn't claim it does. Applying the same technique to your example the conclusion would be that if the limit exists (which it doesn't) it must be 0. The point is simply the SebiSebi's book is wrong, the limit can't be 0.

Comment: And in case anyone wonders why the limit in @SamiBenRomdhane's comment doesn't exist, just consider what happens if we approach $(0,0)$ along the line $x=y$?

Comment: What Henrik wrote in his comment is what I understood: he's proving the limit cannot be zero. Period. Whether it exists or not is another matter. Interestingly enough, WA says the limit is zero...someone is seriously wrong here and I already am not that sure who or what, though I don't usually take too much seriously WA.

Comment: It might be argued that the first $=$ in my answer is wrong, because without knowing that both sides makes sense, I can't really claim equality. With the comment directly below, I do find that to be quite pedantic though.

Comment: @Timbuc WA is utter sh*t when it comes to multivariable limits. I think what it does is that it computes the iterated limits. As for the first equality in this answer, it's not problematic at all if you start with the assumption that the limit exists. Then the equality is perfectly legal and allows us to conclude that the limit can't be zero.

Comment: @GitGud, thanks. I didn't realize that about WA but now that I think of that yes: it is about multivariable limits that I've found WA being wrong several times.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x=r\cos t$ and $y=r\sin t$ so

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} (x^2+y^2)^{x^2y^2}=\lim_{r\to0}r^{\frac12r^4\sin^2(2t)}=1$$
because

$$\lim_{r\to0}r\ln r=0$$

Comment: Please check your solution

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane, perhaps the same mine had: it must be $\;r^4\;$ in the exponent.

Comment: Yes thanks! Fortunately, it doesn't change the result:-)

Comment: It is the same thing I did, so I thought the limit was indeed $1$.
But wolfram tells us is $0$! http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%20x%20-%3E%200%2C%20y-%3E%200%20of%20(x%5E2%20%2B%20y%5E2)%5E(x%5E2%20y%5E2)&t=crmtb01

Comment: @Ant graph the function $f(x,y)=(x^2+y^2)^{x^2y^2}$ and see what happens around $(x,y)=(0,0)$... :). It's so strange, even in 2018 Wolfram says that the limit is $0$!

Answer (score 2):

The limit cannot be $0$ because if so, then

$$\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}} < \delta \Rightarrow |(x^{2} + y^{2})^{(xy)^{2}}| < \epsilon,$$
$$x^{2} + y^{2} < \delta^{2}; x^{2}, y^{2} < \delta^{2},$$
$$(x^{2} + y^{2})^{(xy)^{2}} < \delta^{2\delta^{4}} \leq \epsilon,$$
$$\delta \ln \delta = (\frac{\ln \epsilon}{2})^{1/4}.$$
If
$$\epsilon := 1/2$$
then
$(\ln \epsilon /2)^{1/4}$ becomes meaningless.